# Image width dynamic height overlay

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build an overlay (mouseover) on a image with dynamic height:

```
<div id="one-third">
 <div class="over_menu">Text</div>
 <div class="menu_bg"><img src="one.jpg" class="resp-img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.one-third { width: 33.3333%; }
.menu_bg img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
.menu_bg { position:relative; width: 100%; }
.over_menu { position: absolute; z-index:2; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: #FFFFFF; height: 100%; }
```

Unfortunately the height of "over_menu" is too large, it shows until the whole rest of the page. How else can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Give `position: relative;` to the parent, so that its boundaries are within it:

```
.one-third { width: 33.3333%; position: relative; }
```

Comment: Eugen, if you use `.one-third` extensively in your project, you might want to make the selector more specific: `.some-particular-parent .one-third {position:relative;}`. Changing `position` of the building-block element(s) of a framework throughout the project is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `over_menu` to inside `menu_bg`

```
<div id="one-third">
   <div class="menu_bg">
       <div class="over_menu">Text</div>
       <img src="one.jpg" class="resp-img">
   </div>
</div>
```

Of course you should change your `:hover` condition as well. It would be helpful if you could add a JSFiddle to your question.